# 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String?>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

While unit testing by mocking secure storage using mockito this appears. any help?

```
package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart 82:19  MockFlutterSecureStorage.read
package:some_pack/storage/secure_preferences.dart 37:48           SecureStorage.getToken
test\storage\secure_preferences_test.dart 21:27                   main.<fn>.<fn>
test\storage\secure_preferences_test.dart 17:29                   main.<fn>.<fn>

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String?>'
```

Sample code

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MockFlutterSecureStorage mockFlutterSecureStorage =
      MockFlutterSecureStorage();
  SecureStorage secureStorage =
      SecureStorage(flutterSecureStorage: mockFlutterSecureStorage);

  group('token', () {
    test('when getToken()', () async {
      // Given

      // When
      await secureStorage.getToken();

      // Then
      verify(mockFlutterSecureStorage.read(key: "com.xdev.token_key"));
    });
```

where

```
class MockFlutterSecureStorage extends Mock implements FlutterSecureStorage {}
```

Comment: please share a sample code. thanks

Comment: @reza please check i have put some code or more is needed ?

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with null-safety. some additional steps are added to `mockito` due to null-safety migration. have a look here: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md

Comment: @ruben let me know if your problem solved or not

Comment: i am getting now `MissingStubError: 'read'`

Comment: @ruben please share some code snippets. edit your question.